# Using signal spikes to partition data set in R

Tags: r

I have an example data set that looks like this:

```
Ho<-c(12,12,12,24,12,11,12,12,14,12,11,13,25,25,12,11,13,12,11,11,12,14,12,2,2,2,11,12,13,14,12,11,12,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,14,12,11,13,11,12,13,12,11,12,12,12,2,2,2,12,12,12,12,15)
```

This data set has both positive and negative spikes in it that I would like to use as markers to calculate means on within the data. I would define the start of a spike as any number that is 40% greater or lessor than the number preceding it. A spike ends when it jumps back by more than 40%. So ideally I would like to locate each spike in the data set, and take the mean of the 5 data points immediately following the last number of the spike.

As can be seen, a spike can last for up to 5 data points long. The rule for averaging I would like to follow are:

Start averaging after the last recorded spike data point, not after the first spike data point. So if a spike lasts for three data points, begin averaging after the third spiked data point.

So the ideal output would look something like this:

```
 1= 12.2
 2= 11.8
 3= 12.4
 4= 12.2
 5= 12.6
```

With the first spike being Ho(4)- followed by the following 5 numbers (12,11,12,12,14) for a mean of 12.1

The next spike in the data is data points Ho(13,14) (25,25) followed by the set of 5 numbers (12,11,13,12,11) for an average of 11.8.

And so on for the rest of the sequence.

Comment: Is that a complete example of the output for the data you posted? Can you explain how you got the values 12.2, 11.8, 12.4, 12.2 and 12.6?

Comment: @josilber - first spike-end is `Ho[1]`, `mean(Ho[2:6])` is `12.2` etc etc. I assume this relationship holds for the other values.

Comment: Also, you define a spike as a number that is 40% more or less than the previous point, but then you say "spikes can last for up to 4 data points." So how are you defining a run? What starts and stops it? You've only given an element-wise definition so i don't see any runs in your data.

Comment: @thelateemail How can Ho[1] be a spike end? There's no number that precedes it? Ho[2] seems to fit the definition of a spike, as does Ho[10]. Ho[6] does not. 14/12 is 1.16, not >1.4. Or what am I missing?

Comment: @Vinterwoo But Ho[11] doesn't meet the definition of a spike. It's not different than the number before it. And why doesn't Ho[2] meet your definition?

Comment: @MrFlick - I agree it needs to be specified more precisely, I was just trying to figure out the logic myself.

Comment: I could tell you how to if we were able to use another language like PHP.

Comment: Sorry for some of the confusion, I have edited the post to try and clean up some of my logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is come code that seems to get the same result as you.

```
#Data
Ho<-c(12,12,12,24,12,11,12,12,14,12,11,13,25,25,12,11,13,12,11,11,12,14,12,2,2,2,11,12,13,14,12,11,12,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,1,14,12,11,13,11,12,13,12,11,12,12,12,2,2,2,12,12,12,12,15)
#plot(seq_along(Ho), Ho)

#find changes
diffs<-tail(Ho,-1)/head(Ho,-1)
idxs<-which(diffs>1.4 | diffs<.6)+1

starts<-idxs[seq(2, length(idxs), by=2)]
ends<-ifelse(starts+4<=length(Ho), starts+4, length(Ho))

#find means
mapply(function(a,b) mean(Ho[a:b]), starts, ends)
```

[image: Sample Data]

Answer (score 2):

It kind of seems like you're actually defining a spike to mean differing from the "medium" values in the dataset, as opposed to differing from the previous value. I've operationalized this by defining a spike as being any data more than 40% above or below the median value (which is 12 for the sample data posted). Then you can use the nifty `rle` function to get at your averages:

```
r <- rle(Ho >= mean(Ho)*0.6 & Ho <= median(Ho)*1.4)
run.begin <- cumsum(r$lengths)[r$values] - r$lengths[r$values] + 1
run.end <- run.begin + pmin(4, r$lengths[r$values]-1)
apply(cbind(run.begin, run.end), 1, function(x) mean(Ho[x[1]:x[2]]))
# [1] 12.2 11.8 12.4 12.2 12.6
```